# Transfer SelectOption Values to Dynamin Query

Tags: dynamic-soql, selectoption

Trying to get the values to my Controller that I can change the limit on the displayed List on my Page. I'm Using a dynamic query and everything is working fine but what's below. What am I'm missing?

If instead of `selectOption`, I use `CommandLink` that calls the same Action it works, but don't want that. I want `selectOption` to work!

```
<apex:selectList value="{! PageSize }" size="1" id="resultLimit">
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5">
      <apex:param value="5" name="5" assignTo="{!rowLimit}"/>
   </apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5">
      <apex:param value="5" name="5" assignTo="{!rowLimit}"/>
   </apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10">
      <apex:param value="10" name="10" assignTo="{!rowLimit}" />
   </apex:selectOption>
   <apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20">
      <apex:param value="20" name="20" assignTo="{!rowLimit}" />
   </apex:selectOption>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="results" action="{!resetList}"  status="myStatus"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

On Controller :

```
public String rowLimit = '5';
public String getRowLimit()   {
     if (rowLimit == null || rowLimit == '') {
          return '5'; 
     }
    else {
     return rowLimit;
    }
 }
public void setRowLimit(String limitExp)
   {  
     rowLimit = limitExp;
   }

public void resetList () {
 /* This Method Run the Dynamic Query and reset the List Table on Page */
}
```

Comment: the problem seems like for some reason I cannot set the rowLimit Value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **PageSize** will already hold the selected value, I don't think there is a need to use apex:param. You can directly use PageSize to build a Dynamic Query.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!PageSize}" size="1" id="resultLimit">
<apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="30" itemLabel="30"/>
<apex:selectOption itemValue="40" itemLabel="40"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Whatever value you select, will be stored in PageSize variable.

Comment: yep thanks.. Changed PageSize to rowLimit and removed all the apex:param..Now it works Fine :)